# If/else syntax on password verification in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to javascript and trying to list out the characters missing from a failed password to tell users what they need to input.

```
window.onload = function()
{
   var info = document.getElementById("info");

   var test = document.getElementById("myForm").test;

   test.onclick = function(e)
   {
     e.preventDefault();
     var pw = document.getElementById("myForm").pw.value;

     var formula = /(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}/;

     if(formula.test(pw))
     {
         document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
     }
     else if pw.match(/\d/g) == null {
        info.innerHTML = "You need a number";
        console.log(pw.match(/\d/g))

     } else {

       info.innerHTML = "You need a number."
     }

     };

};
```

The above is just a first run through of checking if the user inputted a password with now numbers. But I keep getting an

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

in chrome dev tools with the pw.match portion underlined. I've looked elsewhere online and my syntax looks correct. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Add your HTML code.

Comment: Shouldn't your `formula` be initialized like this?  `var formula = "/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}/" ;` I added `""` signs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses around the condition of your `if` block.

```
 else if (pw.match(/\d/g) == null) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need some parenthesis

```
else if (pw.match(/\d/g) == null) {
//      ^                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

According to:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp
You have missed ( and ) in else if.